# Determine if the statement below is (always) true. If true, justify your answer. If false, give a counterexample.

Tags: matrices, determinant

Let $A, B, C$ be invertible $n × n$ matrices.

Help me to solve

$\det(B) = \frac {\det(ABC)}{\det(CA)}$

Comment: The determinant of a product of $n\times n$ matrices is the product of the determinants.

Comment: @AndréNicolas i can prove this from the right hand side and prove . But i want to start from left hand side (ie from det(B) ) and prove the answer

Comment: Basically the same proof, somewhat less natural.

Comment: Indeed, it is: $\det(B)=\frac{\det(A)\det(B)\det(C)}{\det(C)\det(A)} = \frac{\det(ABC)}{\det(CA)}$

Comment: (Pedagogical note: if any of $A,B,C$ are non-invertible, the right hand side is undefined.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $A,B,C \in GL_{n}(\mathbb{R})$,

$$\det(B) ~=~ \det(B)\bigg[\frac{\det(A)\cdot\det(C)}{\det(C)\cdot\det(A)}\bigg] ~=~ \frac{\det(ABC)}{\det(CA)}$$

Comment: What is GLn(R)?

Comment: General linear group over $\mathbb{R}$. The elements of the group are invertible $n\times n$ matrices of real numbers.